# How to retrieve an multiple records using JSONARRAY in Android

Tags: android

```
Now currently i am getting only updated data of same user by passing id through url.
```

using this below code....

```
 try {

             JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
                JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.getJSONObject(i);

                value = jb.getString("amount");
                tran_count = jb.getString("tran_count");
                debitstr = jb.getString("debit");
                creditstr = jb.getString("credit");

                pointsmodestr = jb.getString("points_mode");

                updatecpa = value;
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 But i need to retrieve multiple data of same user id.
```

For example:
    Now for above code it is only displaying updated data of same user.
    it displays only one array.

```
[{"id":"46097","user_id":"1066","email":"rahul@gmail.com","rolename":"12","account_no":"3445557752334556","debit":"0","credit":"0","amount":"0","points_mode":"wallet","challan":"","used":"yes","paid_to":"00","pay_type":"0","tranx_id":"One time Sponsorship Charges Deduction","active":"0","created_at":"1497008167","modified_at":"1497008167","tran_count":"3"}]
```

How to display multiple JSONARRAY in android of same user

example:

```
1st array of user id=1066    [{"id":"46097","user_id":"1066","email":"rahul@gmail.com","rolename":"12","account_no":"3445557752334556","debit":"0","credit":"0","amount":"0","points_mode":"wallet","challan":"","used":"yes","paid_to":"00","pay_type":"0","tranx_id":"One time Sponsorship Charges Deduction","active":"0","created_at":"1497008167","modified_at":"1497008167","tran_count":"3"}]
```

2nd Array of user id=1066

```
[{"id":"27098","user_id":"1066","email":"rahul@gmail.com","rolename":"12","account_no":"3445557752334556","debit":"0","credit":"0","amount":"0","points_mode":"wallet","challan":"","used":"no","paid_to":"00","pay_type":"2","tranx_id":"Referral offer","active":"0","created_at":"1492671459","modified_at":"1492671459","tran_count":"2"}]
```

Comment: what is mean by multiple records ?

Comment: multiple records means multiple array information of user  (1st array,2nd array .....n-array)

Answer (score 0):

In code, only value is getting added to list, why?
    Hope jsonStr should be proper and on

```
 JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

code will get below kind of jsonArray. If it is the case, it will be retrieved perfectly. and it will be in this kind of format

```
`[{"id":"46097","user_id":"1066","email":"rahul@gmail.com","rolename":"12","account_no":"3445557752334556","debit":"0","credit":"0","amount":"0","points_mode":"wallet","challan":"","used":"yes","paid_to":"00","pay_type":"0","tranx_id":"One` time Sponsorship Charges Deduction","active":"0","created_at":"1497008167","modified_at":"1497008167","tran_count":"3"},
     {"id":"27098","user_id":"1066","email":"rahul@gmail.com","rolename":"12","account_no":"3445557752334556","debit":"0","credit":"0","amount":"0","points_mode":"wallet","challan":"","used":"no","paid_to":"00","pay_type":"2","tranx_id":"Referral offer","active":"0","created_at":"1492671459","modified_at":"1492671459","tran_count":"2"},<another value>]
```

In your code, instead of

```
  for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    please change to
    for(i=0;i<jr.length();i++) {  //as till the last jsonarray it will traverse.
```

if  things are not working, mostly jsonStr must be wrong
Hope that helps

Comment: Thanx for your reply... I tried  that for(i=0;i<jr.length();i++)  but it is not working, length is nt retrieving .

Comment: initially I tried to display in list so added in list....     but list is nt problem, problem is it nt displaying the multiple JSONArray,        
                 for(i=0;i<jr.length();i++) {
                JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.getJSONObject(i);        ///////////  JSONArray length() is nt retrieving and if i is increment then json returns null or empty value  }

Comment: display jsonStr and check whether it is in correct json format.Using https://jsonlint.com/ you can check it. If it is valid, JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(jsonStr) surely has proper JSONArray and in that case jr.length() will work perfectly